# Integrating BIRTViewer and YUI

Tags: yui, birt

I'm Using the BIRTViewer. How can I Integrate the Report generated in the Viewer in a better Web UI framework say like YUI.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jsp than you can use [tag library](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/viewerUsage2.2.php#tags) provided for it